# ‘Updating API Integration for Pro Hosted’

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We recently made changes for the ‘Updating API Integration for Pro Hosted’

> Updated these files: \includes\modules\payment\paypal.php
>   \includes\modules\payment\paypal_ipn.php
>
> Find: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
>
> Updated by Replace with:
>   https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess

But now our customers cannot proceed in the checkout and get this error message:

> Error Processing Payment Your payment can't be processed at this time.
>   Please try again later.

Please can someone assist us and help us resolve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In PayPal's instruction, PayPal don't suggest merchant to hard code https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_hosted-payment in their script, so they advise merchant to replace this URL, but you don't need to replace 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' , this URL has no issue, it's PayPal's endpoint. You need to find this specific link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_hosted-payment , then replace it according to the instruction.